# Let Us make man in Our Image

Tags: genesis, creation, adam, image-of-god

How is the creation of the physical first man an image of the spiritual God?

What is the “design” of the first man that represents “Our image?”

> Gen 1:26, 27 - Then God said, “Let Us make man in Our image, after Our
> likeness, to rule ...”
>
> So God created man in His own image; in the image of God He created
> him; male and female He created them.

Comment: Welcome to BH, and thanks for your question. Have you taken the tour to see how this site works? "What does "image" in Genesis 1:26-27 mean? has 41 answers so your question may [not definitely] be deemed a duplicate.

Comment: I asked a specific question. It has not been asked before, and it certainly hasn’t been answered yet.

Comment: This seems quite similar to the existing question. If you think it is distinct, then please [edit] it to clearly ask a different question that isn't covered by the existing question.

Answer (score 0):

> Christ is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of every
> creature. He is before all things and by Him all things consist.

Colossians 1:15-17

Christ has hands, arms, feet, legs, eyes, a noise, hair, a mouth, he ate and walked and talked.

Adam and Eve were therefore created in the literal image God Himself would take.

Due to the above passage and Proverbs 8:23-24 we can understand that the very first thought God had was of the wise plan concerning Christ. Everything comes from God's thoughts therefore and thereby the physical man Christ was first.

Edit:

The design of the first man that represents the image of God, is therefore Christ, who is a man as we are, with the same general physical features.

Let us make man in our image.
Or
Let us make man in the image that we will take.
Or
Let us make man look like us.

Us, being Father and Son.
The Father is an ever present spirit that just is and always was.
The Son is the physical manifestation of the Father.
Before creation the Father set apart a part of His spirit
for the purpose of giving birth to and indwelling the physical man Christ Jesus.

Christ is a human, and we are humans, Adam and Eve were humans,
therefore they had, we have, the image of God,
if and when we see God, we would see a man.
According to the Bible the physical man Christ is the only way God can be seen. Christ is a man, we mankind have many of the features of the man Christ, like hands and so on, the man Christ represents and is the image of God, as specifically stated in scripture (above) therefore if we look like Christ in any way, we look like God, literally. We have feet and so on, just like the image of God, Jesus, does. It's very literal is what I'm saying.

Comment: _Christ has hands, arms, feet, legs, eyes, a noise, hair, a mouth, he ate and walked and talked. Adam and Eve were therefore created in the literal image God Himself would take._ Yes, agreed. Up-voted +1.